# why extra div is render when m redering a view in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-templates

why extra div is render when m redering a view in backbone.js

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  template :_.template( 
        '<li id="user-<%=user.username%>" class="pp-entry group">'+
            '<img src="i/pp-pic-1.png" class="pp-pic" alt="" />'+
            '<span class="whisper-mode-on hide" title="Whisper mode on"></span>'+
            '<h6 class="pp-name"><%=user.firstname%>&nbsp; <%if(user.lastname!="null"){%><%=user.lastname%><%}%></h6>'+
            '<p id="chat-<%=user.username%>"class="pp-msg"></p>'+
        '</li>'), 
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'close');
    this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    this.model.view = this;
  }, 
  // Re-render the contents of the User item.
  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

                $("#participant-window").prepend(this.el);
}
});
```

when it is getting it is rendering like this :

```
<ul id="participant-window" class="scroll-pane" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; width: 357px;">
<div>
<li id="user-ashutosh" class="pp-entry group" style="cursor: default;">
<img class="pp-pic" alt="" src="i/pp-pic-1.png">
<span class="whisper-mode-on hide" title="Whisper mode on"></span>
<h6 class="pp-name">Ashutosh&nbsp; </h6>
<p id="chat-ashutosh" class="pp-msg"></p>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

why li is inserted in a div how should i stop this ?

Comment: Can you show the line that constructs the instance of your `View`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this line:

```
$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
```

...you set the contents of `this.el` to the template output. If somehow the `el` member variable was already initialized as an existing `div` element, you're just changing it's contents, then appending to the `#participant-window`.

Perhaps try:

```
this.el = $(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));
```

Comment: You might want to use this.delegateEvents() after changing this.el.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you shouldn't reassign el

Comment: `this.setElement($(this.template(this.model.toJSON())));` seems like a better approach.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement

Answer (score 2):

Unless you override it a Backbone.View's `el` property is initialized to a div tag.

So `$(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));` will put the evaluated template into the div tag.

From your code sample it looks like what you actually want to do is to set `this.el` to `$("ul#participant-window")`. Then all you have to do in render is

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
}
```